# Uniformly distributed random values of different bit count

Tags: c++, random

I need to generate random variables for different bit counts.
I came up with the following way to do it:

```
constexpr const std::size_t bit_count = 77U;

std::uint_fast32_t seed = 0U;
try
{
    std::random_device rd;
    seed = rd(); // may throw
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    //simply use time as seed then
    seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
}
std::mt19937 mt(seed);

using number_t = std::vector<bool>;
std::vector<number_t> numbers;

for(std::size_t h = 0U; i < how_many_numbers; ++h)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 1);
    numbers.push_back(number_t());
    auto& num = numbers.back();
    num.resize(bit_count);
    for(std::size_t i = 0U; i < bit_count; ++i)
        num[i] = (dist(mt) == 0);
}
```

Will this be uniformly distributed and behave almost as it would have been generated directly?

If not: How could you do so? I really need those different bit sizes for hashing purposes, so just using some primitive type is not that type of an option, especially since the bit count might be 8192, but not greater. Since the bit count is variable and for learning purposes, I want/need to do it by hand.

Comment: If a value is truly random, then any individual bit is also random. Which means you can split them or concatenate them or swap them any which way and the result will still be random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should give you uniformly distributed numbers in the interval [0, 2^bit_count).

You are getting numbers where every bit has 1/2 chance of being 0 or 1. Given some bit_count there are 2^bit_count numbers and every single number (i.e. single specific combination of bits) has (1/2)^bit_count chance to be generated. So every number has the same chance to be generated.

There would be more efficient ways to represent and generate those numbers however.